# Is there any Screen Recording + Video Editing software like Camtasia for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, screencast, video-recording

I like Camtasia because it got really handy features specially for making instructional videos or tutorials.

Though, I've found try installing Camtasia exe file on Ubuntu using Wine, but I'm not sure if it will be working or not. Even, if it will, will it be effective that way? I'm kinda confused. Do anyone have experience on it? Please let me know.

Or, recommending a good video editor will be a good option too. Cause, I like the Screen Capturing of Kazam.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for information about an app and how well behaved it is under WINE is https://appdb.winehq.org/ and the reviews https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=7983 of Camtasia under WINE are poor.  Evidently the programming of Camtasia does not use documented APIs.

Alternatives are listed at https://alternativeto.net/software/camtasia-studio/?platform=linux although we are abjured from making recommendations regarding applications. For that, please visit http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .